# Problem running follower demo turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just received a turtlebot and I'm having some trouble when I try to run the follower demo in the netbook that came along with the robot. The robot doesn't move when I run the command: $ roslaunch turtlebot_follower follower.launch

The output is:

```
[ INFO] [1405090576.551327448]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1405090576.551600322]: 1. device on bus 003:24 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1405090576.553242502]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1405090576.603033557]: Opened 'SensorV2' on bus 3:24 with serial number '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1405090577.265245722]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1405090577.265818846]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1405090577.280437487]: Camera calibration file /home/turtlebot/.ros/camera_info/rgb_0000000000000000.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1405090577.280986866]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1405090577.281605477]: Camera calibration file /home/turtlebot/.ros/camera_info/depth_0000000000000000.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1405090577.281993724]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

I think it should have shown 2 devices connected (kinect and kobuki base).
I tried disconnecting each one of them and running the code again and I discovered that the problem is that it is only considering the kinect as a connected device.
Do I need to do anything else than connecting the provided usb cable between the base and the netbook?
Using the command $lsusb it looks like the usb port is working properly.

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:
Thanks for the answer Devon,
I've tried what you suggested but unfortunately it didn't work.
I didn't find the topic cmd_vel, so I used the other command you suggest and the output was:

```
$ rostopic list | grep cmd_vel
/cmd_vel_mux/active, 
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi, 
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_descriptions
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter_updates
/follower_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel
```

I assumed the topic I would like to verify is the last one.
So I ran the follower application again while monitoring the topic, and I could check that it's not sending any velocity commands (assuming the topic I chose is the right one). The output was a bunch of:

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
```

Cheers, gerhenz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186110/problem-running-follower-demo-turtlebot/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has the turtlebot core been started? The follower is the application that runs on the turtlebot. The turtlebot core may need to be started:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

and you can verify that it is sending velocity commands by

```
rostopic echo cmd_vel
```

if you don't see cmd_vel, try:

```
rostopic list | grep cmd_vel
```

and retry the rostopic echo with the output from the above command.

Cheers,
Devon

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-14**:
Devon, I've edited the question regarding the results of your suggestions. Cheers

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-14**:
Thanks. Did you try standing in-front of the robot when the follower.launch is played? There is a dead-zone, so make sure that is out of the way as well.

If that's not the case: please after plugging in the usb to the turtlebot show me the output of cat /var/log/syslog

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-07-14**:
I was trying to stand too close to the kinect (probably inside the dead-zone). Everything works now. Thanks Devon!